# Can't call method "login" on an undefined value at -e line 1

Tags: perl, ncbi

This is the error I'm getting, I copied and pasted a direct set of commands from a website called ncbi that were

```
cd ~
  perl -MNet::FTP -e \
    '$ftp = new Net::FTP("ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov", Passive => 1); $ftp->login;
     $ftp->binary; $ftp->get("/entrez/entrezdirect/edirect.zip");'
  unzip -u -q edirect.zip
  rm edirect.zip
  export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/edirect
  ./edirect/setup.sh
```

I have no idea what to look for because I'm unfamiliar with these commands

Edit
So some things were fixed by someone from the website but I am still trying to type

```
'perl -MNet::FTP -e '$ftp = new Net::FTP("ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov", Passive => 1); $ftp->login; $ftp->binary; $ftp->get("/entrez/entrezezdirect/edirect.zip");'
```

and nothing is happening it's like if I were just to type "cat" because just a blank line happens

Comment: I suspect Perl needs to be told about a proxy? No time to look into how to do that right now

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of things that can go wrong with an FTP connection, and at least one of those things went wrong for you. The [`Net::FTP` docs for `new`](http://metacpan.org/pod/Net::FTP) say that

> If the constructor fails undef will be returned and an error message will be in `$@`

so you can at least start to diagnose the issue with

```
perl -MNet::FTP -e '$ftp=new Net::FTP("ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov", Passive => 1) or print $@'
```

Comment: So nothing happened and then this happened

Net::FTP: connect: Operation timed out

Comment: so some things were fixed by someone from the website but I am still trying to type "perl -MNet::FTP -e '$ftp = new Net::FTP("ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov", Passive => 1); $ftp->login; $ftp->binary; $ftp->get("/entrez/entrezezdirect/edirect.zip");" and nothing is happening it's like if I were just to type "cat" because just a blank line happens @mob

Answer (score 0):

The code it's working fine for me. Try to set the Debug to 1, and paste here the output:

```
cd ~
  perl -MNet::FTP -e \
    '$ftp = new Net::FTP("ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov", Passive => 1, Debug => 1); $ftp->login;
     $ftp->binary; $ftp->get("/entrez/entrezdirect/edirect.zip");'
unzip -u -q edirect.zip
rm edirect.zip
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/edirect
./edirect/setup.sh
```

Comment: Ok, here is the output

-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Comment: That's a bash syntax error. Please, type in the shell all the code that you've pasted previously, but add the Debug param

Comment: Same problem    

Can't call method "login" on an undefined value at -e line 1.

Answer (score -1):

The constructor of Net::FTP is not returning anything. This means that it cannot connect to the host specified.

First, change your script to check the return value of the constructor (`$ftp`) before trying to call the `login` method.

Outside your script you should check that you can connect to the host via FTP. If not, check your machine and firewall settings.

Comment: What would the return value of the constructor ($ftp) be, and this isn't a script it just commands that I'm pasting into the command line, and how would I connect to the host via FTP

Comment: $ftp will be under if you cannot connect to the FTP host. If it does connect, then $ftp will be a fully populated object (that you can call login on)....

Comment: You can use an FTP client to check connectivity outside your provided command. On Linux you can issue "ftp {host}"